# Multiple Mongo Projections

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am running a query from my Meteor server, but for some reason only the first projection is catching.

`Users.find({"services.facebook" : {$exists : true}}, {"_id": {$nin: doNotCount}}).fetch()`

only returns facebook users (disregarding `{"_id": {$nin: doNotCount}}`)

`Users.find(, {"_id": {$nin: doNotCount}}, {"services.facebook" : {$exists : true}}).fetch()`

only returns users not in a given array (disregarding `{"services.facebook" : {$exists : true}}`)

from the documentation, it looks like this is possible:

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/

but im not having any luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is the first parameter only, the second parameter deals with sorting, limits, restricting the fields to be returned etc...

Change to:

```
Users.find({ "services.facebook" : {$exists : true}, "_id": {$nin: doNotCount }}).fetch()
```

Comment: re-read the question...that is the first case that i outlined; it didnt catch the $nin projection

Comment: Look carefully at where the braces are.